# Target a template reference variable from another component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to target a template reference variable in another component?
I would like to trigger the *side nav* by creating an event that calls the sidenav's open function through the TRV `sidenav`.

**app.component.html**

```html
<md-sidenav-layout>

    <md-sidenav #sidenav (open)="mybutton.focus()">
      Start Sidenav.
      <br>
      <button md-button #mybutton (click)="sidenav.close()">Close</button>
    </md-sidenav>

    <top-bar></top-bar>

    <main class="main" (openNav)="sidenav.open()">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

**topbar.component.html**

```html
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <button class="app-icon-button" (click)="openSideNav()">
    <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
  </button>
  <span [routerLink]="['']">Home</span>
  <span [routerLink]="['test']"  class="navlink">Test</span>
  <span class="navlink" (click)="signout()">signout</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

**topbar.component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'top-bar',
  templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.css']
})
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  @Output() openNav = new EventEmitter();
  openSideNav(){
    console.log(this.openNav.emit());
    this.openNav.emit();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Is it possible for me to target the template variable in the app component from the topbar directive?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but you can bind it to the event in topbar and then decide when opening/closing the nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple options.

One, you can create a service that holds the sidenav instance. You can set the sidenav from the app component.

```
class SidenavService {
  private _sidenav: MdSidenav;

  set sidenav(nav: MdSidenav) {
    this._sidenav = nav; 
  } 

  open() {
    if (this._sidenav) this.sidenav.open();
  }

  close() {
    if (this._sidenav) this._sidenav.close();
  }
}
```

And in your app controller

```
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MdSidenav) sidenav: MdSidenav;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sidenavService.sidenav = this.sidenav;
  }
}
```

Then you can inject the `SidenavService` into whatever other component where you want to have access to it.

The other options is to simply have the sidenav as an input to the topbar.

```
<topbar [sidenav]="sidenav"></topbar>

class TopbarComponent {
  @Input() sidenav: MdSidenav;
}
```

I personally don't like the second option, as I don't like exposing the sidenav unnecessarily. I'd rather just use the service and control what others can do with it.